# Как читать clob используя jоператор json_table?

Tags: oracle12c

Данные сохраняться в clob  в таком виде :

```
ga:date,ga:campaign,ga:source,ga:medium,ga:adContent,ga:keyword,ga:deviceCategory,ga:sessions,ga:bounces,ga:sessionDuration,ga:pageviews,ga:transactions,ga:newUsers,ga:transactionRevenue,ga:users
20220111,Teenie_Beanie_Boos_mcd_landing,Yandex_Video,OLV,Common,127892-Parents-Multi-roll_20_sec-R1,mobile,361,132,11469.0,504,0,312,0.0,341
20220111,Teenie_Beanie_Boos_mcd_landing,Yandex_Direct,Banner,Common,127891-Parents-Banner-R3_31,mobile,248,49,11205.0,341,0,192,0.0,234
```

Используя следующий код возвращается 0. :

```
SELECT count(*) into n_row FROM json_table(csv_clob,'$[*]'
columns(
GA_DATE DATE    path    '$.date',
GA_CAMPAIGN VARCHAR2(800 BYTE)  path    '$.campaign',
GA_SOURCE   VARCHAR2(800 BYTE)  path    '$.source',
GA_MEDIUM   VARCHAR2(800 BYTE)  path    '$.medium',
GA_ADCONTENT    VARCHAR2(800 BYTE)  path    '$.adContent',
GA_KEYWORD  VARCHAR2(800 BYTE)  path    '$.keyword',
GA_DEVICECATEGORY   VARCHAR2(800 BYTE)  path    '$.deviceCategory',
GA_SESSIONS NUMBER(6,0) path    '$.sessions',
GA_BOUNCES  NUMBER(6,0) path    '$.bounces',
GA_SESSIONDURATION  VARCHAR2(800 BYTE)  path    '$.sessionDuration',
GA_PAGEVIEWS    NUMBER(6,0) path    '$.pageviews',
GA_TRANSACTIONS NUMBER(5,0) path    '$.transactions',
GA_NEWUSERS NUMBER(18,0)    path    '$.newUsers',
GA_TRANSACTIONREVENUE   NUMBER(18,0)    path    '$.transactionRevenue',
GA_USERS    NUMBER(18,0)    path    '$.users'));
```

В чём причина ?

Comment: *В чём причина ?* Да в том, что значение - вот ни разу не JSON...

Comment: @Akina соглашусь что это не json , а csv.. делал вывод что так можно из этой статьи : https://odieweblog.wordpress.com/2016/04/22/simple-csv-parsing-using-xmltable-or-json_table/

Comment: А то, что в статье исходное значение жуётся до тех пор, пока не превратится в JSON - не заметил, что ли? Впрочем, как бы процесс несложный - откусить первую строку, обкавычить все значения да обернуть правильными скобками. Ну и тянуть надо не по именам, которых нет, а по индексам - т.е. строку надо превращать не в объект, а в массив.

Comment: Попробую обернуть